# Transfer mouse position via usb

Tags: android, position, touchscreen, mouse-cursor

I have a nec tv with elo touch touchpanel. I need to control an android device using the touch of the tv. The android is connected to tv via hdmi and the touchpanel sends inputs via usb.
The problem is that the elo touch doesn't have drivers for android and tech support told me that will come next summer.
It is possible to have a linux/windows pc that gets the inputs from the tv(that is seen as hid device) and send them to the android device using a male to male usb cable? The pc should be seen as a mouse from the android device (it has 4.04 android on it).

Is this possible?